# How to update /sbin/init?

Tags: boot, server, kernel, 15.04, upstart

I am trying to use `Upstart` to daemonize a script. So, I made a `.conf` file under `/etc/init/`. Now to check the conf file I did

```
init-checkconf /etc/init/ping_me.conf
```

And it says

```
ERROR: version of /sbin/init too old
```

My linux kernel version is `3.19.0-20-generic`.

The Upstart is unable to configure the service. Hence `service ping_me start` is not working. So, if `init` can be updated, how can I update it?

Comment: To be noted that 15.04 uses systemd, *not* Upstart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv`, after installing `init-checkconf` work's good. You can activate debug mode in `/usr/bin/init-checkconf`.

Comment: Make a huge note: 15.04 and later use ***SystemD***, and NOT Upstart.

Comment: Is the procedure same for using SystemD? Just creating the `.conf` file inside `/etc/init` should be enough? In my case it's not working. It says `Failed to start ping_me.service: Unit ping_me.service failed to load: No such file or directory.` after doing `service ping_me start`.